# oracle sql developer email alert

Tags: oracle

can you please check this for me 
this is not working
do we need special `utl_mail`
no idea what this `utl_mail` is

```
create or replace 
procedure check_stock_qty
begin

for r  ( select inv_qoh from inventory
                where qty = 0 )
     loop
         UTL_MAIL.send(sender => 'na@yahoo.com',
        recipients => 'krn9@mail.ca',
         subject => 'Test Mail',
         message => (r.inv_qoh),
      mime_type => 'text; charset=us-ascii'); 
     end loop;
end;

BEGIN
    dbms_scheduler.create_job (
        job_name        => 'stock check',
        job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action      => 'BEGIN check_stock_qty; END;',
        start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
        repeat_interval => 'freq=minutely; interval=7200; bysecond=0;',
        end_date        => NULL,
        enabled         => TRUE,
END;
```

my error is

```
Error(2,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:     ( ; is with authid as cluster compress order using compiled    wrapped external deterministic parallel_enable pipelined    result_cache
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for creating the procedure is

```
create or replace procedure <Name>
  (<variable list>)
as (or is)

  local variable declaration
begin
    code section
  exceptions
end;
```

here you missed the `IS` or `AS` Keyword before `BEGIN`

Comment: Plus: a loop must be terminated with `end loop` the call to `create_job` doesn't need an extra `begin`

Answer (score 0):

i tried with as

Error(5,8): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:     in The symbol "in" was substituted for "(" to continue. 
Error(16,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" 
Error(25,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null          continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date       pipe

so much errors :(